# How to access the application context from an android listener

Tags: android, android-context, wallpaper

I have an Android widget (extends the `AppWidgetProvider` class) and I'm trying to access the application context from within a service Listener. I need to access the context so that I can change the application wallpaper. Here's the error I get: `Cannot refer to a non-final variable context inside an inner class defined in a different method`. I tried the suggested fix to change the modifier context to Final but the Bitmap I create comes back as null. Can someone suggestion the appropriate way to handle this? Here's a snippet of the code:

```
private void startWallpaperService(Context context) {
    Intent wpIntent = new Intent(context, Wallpaper_Service.class);
    context.startService(wpIntent);

    Wallpaper_Service wpSrv = Wallpaper_Service.getService();

    if(wpSrv != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Wallpaper Service is not null");

        Wallpaper_Service.repetitionInterval=30*1000;

        wpSrv.setWallpaperListener(new Wallpaper_Service.WallpaperListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWallpaperUpdate(int imageId) {
                if(wpm == null)
                    Log.w(TAG, "wpm or context is null");
                else {
                    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image1);  // I get a syntax error here
                    if(background==null){
                        Log.w(TAG, "background is null");
                    }else{

                        try {
                            wpm.setBitmap(background);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Wallpaper Service failed");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just create a final application context instance in the third line of your method like:

```
final Context ctx  = context.getApplicationContext();
```

or

```
final Context ctx  = context;
```

And I presume you can now use the "ctx" in your inner method deceleration.

This just sounds like a java syntax limitation and not a code issue.

Hope this helps.

-serkan

Comment: Hi Serkan, thanks for your response. I tried this earlier and the background variable created is null. Perhaps there is another issue with the line:  Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image1)

Comment: Np, I wish that worked but interestingly, I use the same line in my app: Bitmap car = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car); which works... I wonder if context.getResources() returns something not quite right?

Comment: Thanks Serkan! There must be an issue with my bitmap. I tried another one and it seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1):

In 95% of situations and always in Listeners you can use directly getApplicationContext() for getting the context.

If you need context for getting system resources, use

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.somestuffofmyown)
```

You can use it everywhere in your application!